# Setting window to fill screen with right resolution

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

The resolution on the Raspberry Pi is restricted to a certain area and doesn't fill the screen. How do we change the resolution to fill the entire screen? A command line or some other option would be able to find the right resolution and set it to that resolution and filling the screen.

Comment: What screen?  What size?  How is it attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to play about with overscan.

```
$ sudo raspi-config
```

Then from Advanced select Overscan. Try both and see if the screen fit is better.